# Error with matplotlib font manager

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run a simple script on my server to test matplolib. The script is as simple as this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # no error here, it works
plt.figure(1).show()
```

However, it is impossible to execute it and I am getting this error:
I run out of ideas to be honest

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1459, in <module>
    fontManager = json_load(_fmcache)
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 986, in json_load
    return json.load(fh, object_hook=_json_decode)
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 332, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 977, in json_dump
    json.dump(data, fh, cls=JSONEncoder, indent=2)
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # no error, it works
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 31, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1469, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1454, in _rebuild
    json_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)
  File "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 979, in json_dump
    warnings.warn('Could not save font_manager cache ', e)
TypeError: category must be a Warning subclass, not 'OSError'
```

Comment: How did you install `matplotlib`? That "No space left on device" things looks highly suspicious, and the path containing `CACHEDDEV1_DATA` seems odd.

Comment: I installed matplolib through pip. That cacheddev1_data folder is where qnap nas stores users folders. It seems is related with memory as randomly the script works but honestly is not a heavy task and I have plenty of ram